# PHAsset, how to retrieve the specific PHAsset object after app restarts (ios8 Photos)

Tags: ios, iphone, photos, alassetslibrary, phasset

I used to use `ALAssetLibrary`. And it has `assetForURL` function, so that I can save the URL in to `NSUserDefaults` and to retrieve `ALasset` by URL after app restarts.

However, when I change to `PHAsset`, I can't find this kind of function. What I found is `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs`,  but it will be deprecated for `ALasset`, so I don't tend to use this function. (save ALAsset url , and retrieve PHAsset from  `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs`)

I think it's the only way to save the whole `PHAsset` object into `NSUserDefaults` with key "localIdentifier", so I can reload it after app restarts. To retrieve phasset object is by key localIdentifier.

Is it a good way to achieve my goal?  Other ways ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is the property `.localIdentifier`. It's "obscure" as it is actually a property of the super-class `PHObject`. Here's what the docs say:

> A unique string that persistently identifies the object. (read-only)
>
> Declaration
>
> SWIFT
>
> `var localIdentifier: String { get }`
>
> Discussion
>
> Use this string to find the object by using the 
>   `fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:`,
>   `fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:`, or
>   `fetchCollectionListsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:` method.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to set entire **PHAsset** object in **NSUserDefaults.**
Just set **localIdentifier** in **NSUserDefaults** for any key like **"photoIdentifier".**

So let's say you have a PHAsset object then

Save localIdentifier using below.

```
PHAsset *assetObject;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:assetObject.localIdentifier forKey:@"PhotoIdentifier"];
```

Now to retrieve that Asset, you need to iterate through Photos Collection and get the exact photo by its Identifier like this.

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
PHFetchResult *allPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:allPhotosOptions];

[allPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset   * _Nonnull photoAsset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

 NSString *photoIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PhotoIdentifier"];
 if([photoIdentifier isEqualToString:photoAsset.localIdentifier]){

     // asset here

    // if you want Image then get UIImage from PHAsset as follows.           

     [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:photoAsset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info){
          if ([info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey] == nil && ![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] boolValue]) {

             // image is here as a result parameter
             *stop = YES;
          }
      }];
   }
 }];
```

Comment: Yes, it can achieve my goal , but enumerate all photos takes lots of time... fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options   is the better. (Thanks , Grimxn )